# How to properly set custom main font, including TOC entries

Tags: table-of-contents, fontspec

I need to set a custom font (installed in my OS) for my documents, according to my company's style guidelines.

I was able to successfully set "Gotham Book" as main font, but for some reason, my TOC results in chapter lines still using the default font (section font is correct instead).

I've searched a lot but probably I'm missing the underlying problem, as I'm still new to Tex.

---

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Gotham Book}
\newfontfamily{\chapterfont}{Gotham Book}
\newfontfamily{\sectionfont}{Gotham Book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{first chapter}
\section{first section}
\lipsum{1}
\section{second section}
\lipsum{1}
\chapter{second chapter}
\lipsum{1}
\section{first section}
\lipsum{1}
\section{second section}
\lipsum{1}
\chapter{third chapter}
\lipsum{1}

\end{document}
```

---

And here's the resulting TOC:

[image: TOC]

Comment: `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles]{scrbook}`

Comment: Note that in the `scrreprt` class, the font for the `section` entries in the ToC is the main font. You can set the font for all titles with `\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor <<Your font>>}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The komascript classes use, by default, the sans serif font family for titles.

Since you're using a sans serif font for the whole document you have a few possibilities. I used DejaVu Sans, not having Gotham Book on my machine.

#### First possibility

Define the sans serif font family

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  12pt,
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}
\setsansfont{DejaVu Sans}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{first chapter}
\section{first section}
\lipsum{1}
\section{second section}
\lipsum{1}
\chapter{second chapter}
\lipsum{1}
\section{first section}
\lipsum{1}
\section{second section}
\lipsum{1}
\chapter{third chapter}
\lipsum{1}

\end{document}
```

#### Second possibility

Change the standard font for titles (the name is `disposition`, probably a bad translation).

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  12pt,
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}

\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{first chapter}
\section{first section}
\lipsum{1}
\section{second section}
\lipsum{1}
\chapter{second chapter}
\lipsum{1}
\section{first section}
\lipsum{1}
\section{second section}
\lipsum{1}
\chapter{third chapter}
\lipsum{1}

\end{document}
```

#### Third possibility

Use the class option for the purpose, which has a rather funny name:

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  12pt,
  egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles,
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{first chapter}
\section{first section}
\lipsum{1}
\section{second section}
\lipsum{1}
\chapter{second chapter}
\lipsum{1}
\section{first section}
\lipsum{1}
\section{second section}
\lipsum{1}
\chapter{third chapter}
\lipsum{1}

\end{document}
```

#### Output

Table of contents

[image]

Chapter page

[image]

<sub>Somehow Markus Kohm realized I suggested a document class option for making titles in serif type (better, in the default font family associated to `\familydefault` instead of sans serif). I had pointed out that using `\setkomafont` for this is awkward: see the “second possibility” in order to understand my point. The answer was the addition of a silly-named option.</sub>

Comment: Perhaps cheating is the simplest way? If the entire document does not use a genuine sans-serif font anywhere, why not `\setsansfont{Gotham Book}` so that Gotham Book (a serif font) is used in place of sans?

Comment: @RobtA Isn't this cover in the first possibility?

Comment: I interpreted the first possibility as being the other way around (using sans everywhere). I must have misunderstood it.

Answer (score 1):

With the `scrreprt` class, the font used for `section` entries in the table of contents is the main document font. In your example, the `\newfontfamily` calls do nothing at all.

You probably want to change all section titles fonts, since by default they use `\normalcolor\sffamily\bfseries` and your font is sans-serif. You can use the `\setkomafont` for this:

```
\setmainfont{Gotham Book}
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalcolor\bfseries}% Removed \sffamily
```

If you only want to change the ToC entries font, use `\setkomafont{chapterentry}{...}` instead.